# Organising data to remove duplicates in certain columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently trying to make an SQL report that can display information on new rows and removed duplicated.

For the sake of this example, I have one column (car) which takes a field from tableA which is then linked to tableB (colour). Something like the table below.

```
-----------------------------
|Car (TableA)|Colour(TableB)|
-----------------------------
|CarA        |Blue          |
|CarA        |Black         |
|CarA        |Yellow        |
|CarB        |Purple        |
|CarB        |Orange        |
|CarB        |Black         |
-----------------------------
```

Instead, I am trying to get my data to show a little something like this:

```
-----------------------------
|Car (TableA)|Colour(TableB)|
-----------------------------
|CarA        |Blue          |
|            |Black         |
|            |Yellow        |
|            |              |
|CarB        |Purple        |
|            |Orange        |
|            |Black         |
-----------------------------
```

Comment: so you're looking to group by car but without the repeated rows?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Yeah pretty much. I know I could have explained that better so I'm sorry I didn't.

Comment: As for the DBMS, Microsoft SQL server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should to the trick:

```
declare @tbl as table (
    car varchar(10)
    ,brand varchar(10)
    ,colour varchar(10)
)

insert into @tbl values ('CarA', 'Tesla', 'Blue')
insert into @tbl values ('CarA', 'Tesla', 'Black')
insert into @tbl values ('CarA', 'Tesla', 'Yellow')
insert into @tbl values ('CarB', 'Kia', 'Purple')
insert into @tbl values ('CarB', 'Kia', 'Orange')
insert into @tbl values ('CarB', 'Kia', 'Black')
insert into @tbl values ('CarC', 'Ford', 'Green')

SELECT
    CASE WHEN rn > 1 THEN '' ELSE car END AS car
    ,colour
FROM (
    SELECT
        car
        ,colour
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY car ORDER BY car, colour ASC) rn
    FROM @tbl
) tbl
```

---

**UPDATE**

Saying you have `brand` between `car` and `colour`:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN rn > 1 THEN '' ELSE car END AS car
    ,CASE WHEN rn > 1 THEN '' ELSE brand END AS brand
    ,colour
FROM (
    SELECT
        car
        ,brand
        ,colour
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY car, brand ORDER BY car, colour ASC) rn
    FROM @tbl
) tbl
```

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to work how I wanted it using your test data.

Say for example I was to add another column in between 'Car' and 'Color' and we titled this column 'Brand'.

How would I go about implementing this into what you've provided? I've had a play around but can't seem to quit figure it out.

The example data could be the same as the above but the brands are as follows: CarA's = Tesla, CarB's = Kia, CarC's = Ford

Comment: Use `PARTITION BY car, brand` ... if this will be your new 'group', to say so; and you use the same `CASE WHEN` on `brand` column

Comment: I've managed to display the brand column but i'm not sure what you mean by the 'case when on brand' part.

At the moment i've got:

`CASE WHEN rn > 1 THEN  ' ' ELSE car END AS car, brand, colour`

If i'm not mistaken it has something to do with the ELSE part of the statement, no?

Comment: don't you want the same behavior for `brand` column as for `car` column?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm aiming for. So `car` and `brand` both have the duplicates removed but `colour` doesn't

Comment: My updated answer does that :) I have also updated the declaration of table with new column

Comment: Ahh that's great, It looks like what I tried came very close but still so far. Really appreciate the help!